# Mosquitto bridge mode error "Client local.XXXXXX.awsiot disconnected: protocol error."

Tags: mqtt, iot, mosquitto, aws-iot, bridge

I'm trying to create a bridge between my local mosquitto broker and AWS IOT. Unfortunatelly i cannot succesfully make it work :(((

I setup the mosquitto.config file like that:

```
port 1883
allow_anonymous true


log_type all
tls_version tlsv1.2
bind_address 0.0.0.0
listener 8883
protocol mqtt

connection awsiot
address al3qi2b1mxp67-ats.iot.us-east-2.amazonaws.com:8883
topic # both 0
try_private false
bridge_protocol_version mqttv311

bridge_keyfile C:\Program Files\mosquitto\certs\private.key
bridge_certfile C:\Program Files\mosquitto\certs\certificate.pem
bridge_cafile C:\Program Files\mosquitto\certs\AmazonRootCA1.pem
```

I'm getting this result in cmd running command `mosquitto.exe -c mosquitto.conf`

```
1642763152: The 'port' option is now deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Please use 'listener' instead.
1642763152: The 'bind_address' option is now deprecated and will be removed in a future version. The behaviour will default to true.
1642763152: mosquitto version 2.0.14 starting
1642763152: Config loaded from mosquitto.conf.
1642763152: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 8883.
1642763152: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 8883.
1642763152: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1642763152: Bridge local.DESKTOP-DC703HB.awsiot doing local SUBSCRIBE on topic #
1642763152: Connecting bridge awsiot (al3qi2b1mxp67-ats.iot.us-east-2.amazonaws.com:8883)
1642763152: Bridge DESKTOP-DC703HB.awsiot sending CONNECT
1642763152: mosquitto version 2.0.14 running
1642763153: Client local.DESKTOP-DC703HB.awsiot disconnected: protocol error.
```

Comment: Have you tried `tls_version tlsv1.3`? TLS 1.2 is rather old and is considered less secure than 1.3. It's possible that AWS will not negotiate to it.

Comment: Yess, seemed that this was the issue:) Weird thing the fact that it worked like the way i had before in my 2nd PC...